How to use more than one property to create an Appointment (Syncfusion SfScheduler .NET MAUI)?
enter image description here
I am trying to create an appointment template but as per my design I have the need to use properties like Background, Notes, and others more than once to create a single appointment. The SchedulerAppointment class blocks this feature and I can't change it. Is there any solution?

What does “blocks this feature” mean?  What is the specific problem?  Please include the relevant code

Please follow the below steps to achieve the requirement:

Create a custom appointment class with the properties that are in need.

Then please use the SchedulerAppointmentMapping to link these properties  to the relevant properties in the SchedulerAppointment.

Afterwards create appointments with all these properties in the custom appointment class.

Finally bind these properties to the AppointmentTemplate using the 'DataItem' property.


Please find the sample code snippet for reference:
Custom appointment class:
public class Event : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 private DateTime eventStartDateTime, eventEndDateTime;

 private string name;

 private Brush appointmentColor;

 private string phoneNumber;

 private string appointmentDetails;



 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;



 public DateTime EventStartDateTime

 {

     get { return eventStartDateTime; }

     set

     {

         eventStartDateTime = value;

         this.RaiseOnPropertyChanged(nameof(EventStartDateTime));

     }

 }



 public DateTime EventEndDateTime

 {

     get { return eventEndDateTime; }

     set

     {

         eventEndDateTime = value;

         this.RaiseOnPropertyChanged(nameof(EventEndDateTime));

     }

 }



 

 public string Name

 {

     get { return name; }

     set

     {

         name = value;

         this.RaiseOnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));

     }

 }



 public Brush AppointmentColor

 {

     get { return appointmentColor; }

     set

     {

         appointmentColor = value;

         this.RaiseOnPropertyChanged(nameof(AppointmentColor));

     }

 }



 public string PhoneNumber

 {

     get { return phoneNumber; }

     set

     {

         phoneNumber = value;

         this.RaiseOnPropertyChanged(nameof(PhoneNumber));

     }

 }



 public string AppointmentDetails

 {

     get { return appointmentDetails; }

     set

     {

         appointmentDetails = value;

         this.RaiseOnPropertyChanged(nameof(AppointmentDetails));

     }

 }





 /// <summary>

 /// Invoke method when property changed.

 /// </summary>

 /// <param name="propertyName">property name</param>

 private void RaiseOnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)

 {

     this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

 }

}
ViewModel class:
public class BusinessObjectViewModel
{
#region Constructor

public BusinessObjectViewModel()
{
    this.IntializeAppoitments();
}

#endregion Constructor


#region Properties


/// <summary>

/// Gets or sets appointments.

/// </summary>

public ObservableCollection<Event> Events { get; set; }


#endregion


#region Methods

/// <summary>

/// Method to initialize the appointments.

/// </summary>

private void IntializeAppoitments()

{

    this.Events = new ObservableCollection<Event>();



    var meeting = new Event();

    **meeting.EventStartDateTime = DateTime.Now;**

    **meeting.EventEndDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);**

    **meeting.Name = "Robert Fox";**

    **meeting.PhoneNumber = "+447591441001";**

    **meeting.AppointmentDetails = "Lorem ipsum dolor";**

    **meeting.AppointmentColor = Brush.Purple;**

    this.Events.Add(meeting);
                   
}

#endregion

}
MainPage.xaml:
<ContentPage.Resources>
<DataTemplate x:Key="dayAppointmentTemplate">

    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />

            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <BoxView Background="Green" WidthRequest="4" Grid.Column="0"/>

        <StackLayout Background="{Binding DataItem.AppointmentColor}" Grid.Column="1">

            <Label **Text="{Binding DataItem.Name}"** TextColor="White" />

            <Label **Text="{Binding DataItem.PhoneNumber}"** TextColor="White"/>

        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Background="{Binding DataItem.AppointmentColor}" Grid.Column="2">

            <Label **Text="{Binding DataItem.AppointmentDetails}"** TextColor="White"/>

            <Label **Text="{Binding DataItem.EventStartDateTime}"** TextColor="White"/>

        </StackLayout>

    </Grid>

</DataTemplate>

</ContentPage.Resources>
<scheduler:SfScheduler x:Name="Scheduler"
                   AppointmentsSource="{Binding Events}"

                   View="Day">

   

<scheduler:SfScheduler.DaysView>

    <scheduler:SchedulerDaysView AppointmentTemplate="{StaticResource dayAppointmentTemplate}"/>

</scheduler:SfScheduler.DaysView>

   

**<scheduler:SfScheduler.AppointmentMapping>**

    **<scheduler:SchedulerAppointmentMapping**

               **StartTime="EventStartDateTime"**

               **EndTime="EventEndDateTime"**

               **Subject="Name"**

               **Background="AppointmentColor"**

               **Notes="AppointmentDetails"/>**

**</scheduler:SfScheduler.AppointmentMapping>**

   

<scheduler:SfScheduler.BindingContext>

    <local:BusinessObjectViewModel />

</scheduler:SfScheduler.BindingContext>

   

</scheduler:SfScheduler>
This way, the custom appointments can be created with all the properties that are in need and display them in the scheduler according to the custom template.
